# Automatically restarting killed Python process executed within a multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import urllib.request
from time import sleep

connected = False

def check_internet_connection() -> None:
    while True:
        print(f'inet', flush=True)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com', timeout=1)
            connected = True
        except urllib.request.URLError:
            connected = False
        finally:
            sleep(5 - time.time() % 5)

def loop(delay: float = 0.5) -> None:
    while True:
        print(f'loop with delay {delay}', flush=True)
        sleep(delay - time.time() % delay)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        while True:
            pool.apply_async(func=check_internet_connection)
            pool.map_async(func=loop, iterable=[0.5, 1.0])
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

Current behavior: If I kill one of the Python processes spawned by multiprocessing, it does not get restarted.

Wanted behavior: The process should be restarted immediately.

If I leave out the `pool.close()` and `pool.join()`, I get my desired behavior. However, the memory consumption increases at an incredible rate and causes my PC to crash within a few minutes.

My alternative approach was this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def loop(delay: float) -> None:
    while True:
        print("Function with delay", delay)
        time.sleep(delay - time.time() % delay)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop, args=(0.5,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop, args=(1.0,))
                
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
                           
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

However, this does also not restart the killed process until both processes are killed.

Edit: My overall goal is to be able to execute a number of functions that each poll sensor values with different delays and write them to separate files. If there is a working internet connection, I also want to send the sensor data to my server. Since I do not want to lose any data, the processes should restart as fast as possible in case they die. Maybe the approach via multiprocessing is not suited at all for this problem. If you have any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: If you leave out `pool.close()` and `pool.join`, you're not *restarting* jobs when they die, you're creating an infinite number of jobs, most of which sit in a queue indefinitely (taking up memory). It is likely that you could improve your code more easily by preventing the workers from dying (e.g. with exception handling), rather than by restarting them afterwards.

Comment: It sounds like the simplest solution to this would just be to have separate processes (and possibly py files) for each of the sensors? Is there a reason you need it to be linked to one main process? Even if does need to be linked to a main process, would there be an issue to have the main process as a flask or fastapi server?

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the explanation. Regarding exception handling: the processes have not yet died at all. In my main code, I do exception handling. Regardless, I want to make the code as robust as possible.

Comment: @arrmansa Thanks for the input. You are right; I also considered your approach. There is no need for the processes to be tied to one main process. How do I create separate processes without having different py files?

Comment: @isThatHim You could have 1 py file started multiple times with arguments using a shell script (or batch file in windows). Use `sys.argv` to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `multiprocessing.Pool` does not support workers termination.

The [`pebble`](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/) library has been developed to cover these limitations. It automatically handles failed jobs and restart workers. Yet it is a [process pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) designed to handle a list of tasks and if a task fails it will move on to the next one.

Therefore, you need to find means to track which task fail and re-submit it. Here is a simple example on how you can do it.

```
import time
import pebble
from concurrent.futures import wait, FIRST_EXCEPTION


def loop(delay: float = 0.5) -> None:
    while True:
        print(f'loop with delay {delay}', flush=True)
        time.sleep(delay - time.time() % delay)


jobs = []
pool = pebble.ProcessPool()


for delay in [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]:
    future = pool.schedule(loop, args=[delay])
    # Add delay to the Future object
    future.delay = delay
    jobs.append(future)


while True:
    futures = []

    # Wait for any job to fail
    wait(jobs, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)

    # Retrieve failed and running jobs
    running_jobs = [f for f in jobs if f.running()]
    failed_jobs = [f for f in jobs if not f.running()]

    # Re-schedule failed jobs
    for future in failed_jobs:
        future = pool.schedule(loop, args=[future.delay])
        futures.append(future)

    jobs = running_jobs + futures
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @noxdafox. I tried using pebble and got it to work. Whenever I kill one of the processes, it is restarted. However, the functions executed by the killed process seem not to be executed again.
If you have time, could you provide me with a minimum example based on the code I gave above? Thank you so much.